# How to reset iPhone to factory settings from computer if screen doesn't work?

Tags: iphone, ios

I dropped the phone and the screen is not responding. 
Before I take it to get it fixed I want to restore the iPhone to factory settings because I'm logged in on my apps, and I don't want the person fixing the phone to get access to my Facebook and other accounts. 
I tried to turn it on again but the screen is not responding.

How can I reset my iPhone from computer if the screen doesn't work?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, placing the iPhone into recovery mode, then connecting to iTunes and restoring will do the trick. Here's an Apple-provided article on how to place the iPhone in recovery mode: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1808

Make sure you use the official Apple to USB lightning connector when attempting this recovery process. I tried several non-apple cables and I was unable to follow the recovery process and generated errors in the recovery process. As soon as i used an official Apple cable - no issue.

Answer (score 2):

Another, less destructive option relies on you having an iCloud account assigned with the phone.

Simply visit the iCloud website, and follow the links for the Find My iPhone app. Once there, you have the option to lock your phone.

This means that the furthest anyone could get when replacing the screen is the unlock screen and that you don't have to go through the hassle of restoring from backups.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the phone to your computer, open iTunes, hit restore.
If the phone is code-protected put it into DFU-Mode first. http://www.iclarified.com/entry/?enid=1034